# Unable to create more than 255 MQTT Connections with RabbitMQ Broker inside TCPListner in python

Tags: python, rabbitmq, mqtt

Through TCPListner of python class `ThreadedTCPServer` i am not able to get mqtt connection more than 250-255 when connecting to RabbitMQ broker following is my code :

```
class service(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
     client.subscribe("subscribe")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print "Received on Topic : '"+str(msg.topic)+"'  and Message is :   "+str(msg.payload)




strConnName="MQTT-Pub-Sub-"+str(self.client_address)

mqttc = mqtt.Client(strConnName,True,threadcounter)
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
mqttc.on_message = on_message
mqttc.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
mqttc.connect("BROKERIP", 1883, 1000)
mqttc.loop_start()

 while True:

       data = self.request.recv(8192)
    if data:
        mqttc.publish("routing_key",str(data))

class ThreadedTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):
    pass

SocketServer.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
t = ThreadedTCPServer((socket.gethostname(),PORT), service)
t.serve_forever()
```

So, when connecting to broker I am creating distinct connection for each new TCP request, But it is not going above 255.

Is there any limit for python `ThreadedTCPServer` Class  or  any thing missing or need to be configured. Although my machine `ulimit -n is  8012`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the ulimit settings for the user that runs the RabbitMQ server.  `rabbitmqctl report` should give you that information under `file_descriptors`